# Updating WooCommerce Subscriptions Order line Items programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscriptions, orders

I am trying to allow users to update line items of their subscriptions from their my account panel. I am able to get their subscription from subscription id and show them update form. Right now I show them with product items in their subscription that I got through

```
$subscription = wcs_get_subscription($_GET['subscription']);
$subscription_items = $subscription->get_items();
```

What I am trying to do is allow users to update quantities of their product. So If they update quantity I want to update the subscription's item quantity so that future orders are generated with updated quantity. 
I saw there is update_product method in `WC_Abstract_Order` class. I think this can be used but I am confused on this note in comments:

```
* Update a line item for the order.
*
* Note this does not update order totals.
```

Do I need to recalculate totals when I use this? 
Also I needed to remove line item when quantity was 0. Is that possible?

As I do not see a remove item method.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I was able to make this work doing following.

1. Remove all order items from subscription object.
2. Run through the $_POST  to get changed quantity
3. Add product to subscription again.

note: I am using custom field price_level as it was dynamically priced during subscription and we wanted to use it so that price was same as when they subscribed.

```
    //remove product items
    $subscription->remove_order_items('line_item');
    //add product item again
    foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $product_id => $qty) {
        if($qty > 0) {
            //we will need to set dynamic prices based on cusotm field
            $price_level = get_field('coffee_price_level', $subscription->id);
            //Get the product
            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
            //set the price
            $product->set_price(floatval($price_level));
            $tax = ($product->get_price_including_tax()-$product->get_price_excluding_tax())*$qty;
            //subscription item price level
            $subscription->add_product($product, $qty, array(
                'totals' => array(
                    'subtotal'     => $product->get_price(),
                    'subtotal_tax' => $tax,
                    'total'        => $product->get_price(),
                    'tax'          => $tax,
                    'tax_data'     => array( 'subtotal' => array(1=>$tax), 'total' => array(1=>$tax) )
                )
            ));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Yalamber, would you be able to provide a bit more context as far as what hooks you used to run this? I'm doing almost exactly the same thing right now and I'm struggling to figure out the best way to implement the edit form.

Comment: I'd suggest using the wp_loaded action.  Keep in mind that WooCommerce Subscriptions uses wp_loaded with a priority of 100.  If you want your function to run after that, use 101: add_action('wp_loaded', [$this, 'wcs_do_subscription_actions'], 101);

Answer (score 3):

Normally in woocommerce when an order is generated after payment (I mean checkout => thankyou), you can't edit anymore the order details. Updating quantities, removing/adding items are WC cart methods.

With subscriptions plugin, with each initial shop_order post-type, there is an initial shop_subscription post-type and a scheduled-action post-type generated at the same time (and post IDs follow each other). For example:

```
Initial (post type) 'shop_order' -> ID is        412
Initial (post type) 'shop_subscription' -> ID is 413  (and 'post_parent': 412)
Initial (post type) 'scheduled-action' -> ID is  414
```

You can see that in your database **`wp_posts`** table.

We could have updated the total in **`wp_postmeta`** table for **`'post_id' => '413'`** with the corresponding **`meta_key`** **`'_order_total'`** using in this case the **`update_post_meta()`** function.

> **BUT this will not work, because the next scheduled subscription payment is handled by the payment gateway** (paypal or others) and **you can't change any amount of that subscription.**
>
> WooCommerce will just generate the new order triggered by this payment gateway, when a scheduled subscription is due.

The only way is to cancel the subscription and generate a new process from the beginning…

Comment: Thank you for the response. I see there is possibility of editing subscription product quantity in backend when we view subscription. How are those handled? Do they create new subscription when we edit quantity?

Comment: @Yalamber  You can't really edit that because you are changing amounts, and as I have said, once subscription has been subscribed, WooCommerce is not handling the scheduled payments. This is handled by the payment gateway or bank (paypal or others). Even if you change amounts in woocommerce, that is not going to be updated on the payment gateway or bank… And payment will remain the same as it was defined with the first order.

Comment: Oh I got it now, I actually do not need to update the amount on payment gateway. Since I will be limiting total quantity of the products to same and each product will have same price. I just need to provide ability to change the qty between different products.

Comment: So I guess for my needs it's ok to update the meta fields right?

Comment: Please don't make this personal. I just provided what worked for me. So I choosed my answer and upvoted yours. as it helped me look in to db and gave related pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Its an old thread but in case its of any help to other people. You can just use the $subscription->remove_item function and then $subscription->save.

In your case:

```
$item_ids_to_remove = array();
// 1. get the item ids that should be removed
foreach ( $subscription->get_items() as $item ) {
    if ($item->get_quantity() == 0) {
        $item_ids_to_remove[] = $item->get_id();
    }
}
// 2. remove the items from the subscription
foreach ($item_ids_to_remove as $item_id_to_remove) {
    $subscription->remove_item($item_id_to_remove);
}
// 3. recalculate totals (incl. tax) and save
$subscription->calculate_totals();
$subscription->save();
```